# Updating ListView On Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I apologize if this is similar to other threads, but I have yet to find a good solution on how to update the ListView in my custom ArrayAdapter.

I'm extending FragmentActivity in order to create a custom Dialog popup for adding / updating new List entries (which works fine), but I can't seem to get the ListView in ServerActivityArrayAdapter to update after a change is made.

Obviously, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in the ServersActivity class isn't enough, but I'm stumped as to how to get my ListView to update after the Save button is clicked in the ServerDialog popup.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class ServersActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private List<Server> server;
private ListView lv;
private ServerActivityArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server_list);

    server = getServers();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter = new ServerActivityArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.server_list_item, server);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            showServerDialog(position);
        }
    });
}

...

private void showServerDialog(int position) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ServerDialog serverDialog = new ServerDialog(position);
    ServerDialog.newInstance();
    serverDialog.show(fragmentManager, "server_dialog");
}
```

ServerDialog class for adding new List entries

```
public class ServerDialog extends DialogFragment {

...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_fragment, container);

    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    dbh = new DbHandler(context);

    etName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etAddress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    etPort = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPort);
    swtchNumDoors = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.swtchNumDoors);
    Button btnSave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    loadData();
    String title = (!newServer) ? "Edit Server" : "Add A New Server " + ID;
    getDialog().setTitle(title);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            server[ID] = String.valueOf(ID);
            server[SERVER_NAME] = etName.getText().toString();
            server[ADDRESS] = etAddress.getText().toString();
            server[PORT] = etPort.getText().toString();

            if (server[ADDRESS].isEmpty() || server[PORT].isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid Entry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                saveData();
                // TODO - notify ServersActivity of change
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public class ServerActivityArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Server> {

private int layout;
private String[][] values;
private int defServer;

private static LayoutInflater inflater;
```

ServerActivityArrayAdapter class for displaying ListView

```
public ServerActivityArrayAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Server> servers) {
    super(context, layout, servers);

    this.layout = layout;

    int i = 0;
    values = new String[servers.size()][5];

    for (Server server : servers) {
        values[i][0] = Integer.toString(server.id);
        values[i][1] = server.name;
        values[i][2] = server.address;
        values[i][3] = Integer.toString(server.port);
        values[i][4] = Integer.toString(server.num_doors);
        defServer = (server.default_server) ? i : 0;
        i++;
    }

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvServerName;
    private CheckBox cbDefault;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;

    try {
        if(v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvServerName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvServerName);
            holder.cbDefault = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbDefault);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvServerName.setText(values[position][1]);
        holder.cbDefault.setChecked(defServer==position);

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Where is your saveData() method?

Comment: It's in ServerDialog and basically just writes values back to a SQLite db. If I close and reopen ServerActivity, the changes are reflected.

Comment: well there you go then, you need to either instantiate a new adapter with a new list from the getServer method or add a method in your adapter to refresh the list. Your adapter will not be notified of changes that happen to the dataset with your current configuration.

Comment: Ok great, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an interface and have a method in it maybe named updateListView().

Implement this interface in your FragmentActivity. In the implemented method, add code to update the listView.

And in the button code of your dialog, call ((Interfacename) getActivity).updateListView()

Comment: I ended up adding a listener in my ServerDialog class that tied to my ServersActivity to pass the updates back and forth based on the examples here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the implementation of the adapter. You are instantiating the `ArrayAdapter` with a `List<Server>` object (The super call) but then creating your own two dimensional array `values` to contain the data.  You use the `values` array for the `getView()` method yet make no mention or show through code how you actually modify that data to update the adapter.

You should be calling back into the adapter to update it.  EG, calling `add()`, `remove()`, etc.  You only mention updating the DB which has nothing to do with updating your adapter. It's not linked in anyway to the DB.  Even if you were to call into the previously mentioned mutate methods on the adapter, they wouldn't work unless you specifically `override` them.  The default `ArrayAdapter` implementation will modify the `List<Server>` data and not the `values` two-dim array you created.

But if you find yourself `override` those mutate methods to support your `values` two-dim array...there's no point in subclassing the `ArrayAdapter`.  Part of the point of the `ArrayAdapter` is handling all the data management for you.  In such a situation you should be instead subclassing `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I see what you are saying about using the values array vs my List<Server> object and have been working on updating my code to implement your suggestions.